# Compare input date with epoch time jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, date, epoch

I have snippet I wrote up, though I am a beginner at jQuery & JavaScript so I have no idea what is wrong with the piece of code. I did substantial Googling & StackOverflow searching, to no avail.

I am attempting to retrieve the date from a date field that a user has input (field is: #input_1_12), and compare it with other date times that have been passed as epoch times. When I run the form, the field I want to populate with the code (id: #input_1_111) stays empty.

p.s. I am implementing this in a WordPress site, so I used "jQuery" instead of "$" in the if statement to make sure there's no compatibility issues.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var saveDate =  new Date($('#input_1_12').val());
var firstQdate = new Date(1554076800);
var secondQdate = new Date(1561939200);
var q1of19 = $('#input_1_22').val();
var q1of20 = $('#input_1_26').val();
var q2of19 = $('#input_1_23').val();
var result;

if ( saveDate < firstQdate ) {
 result = q1of19 / q1of20 ;
jQuery('#input_1_111').val(result).trigger('change');
}
else if ((saveDate > firstQdate) && (saveDate < secondQdate)) {
 result = q2of19 / q1of20 ;
jQuery('#input_1_111').val(result).trigger('change');
}
```

Comment: Your "epoch times" appear to be seconds, the Date constructor expects milliseconds so multiply them by 1,000. What is the actual value returned by `$('#input_1_12').val()`?

Comment: @RobG so if I change the epoch variables to milliseconds - firstQdate = 1554076800000 , and secondQdate = 1561939200000, would that solve that issue? And the #input_1_12 field is dependent on what the user enters into the field. It is any date in between Jan 1st of 2019 through 2021.

Comment: The format of a date string (timestamp) determines how it is parsed. Strings in YYYY-MM-DD format are treated as UTC, others with an offset might consider the offset, others without an offset might be treated as local, hence my question on the actual value returned by the input that is passed to `new Date()`.